# What is the regex validation for positive and negative numbers?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I currently have a regex validator to restrict the user to only input numbers greater than 1. How can I allow both positive and negative numbers?

```
^[1-9]+([0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Add `-?`: `^-?[1-9]([0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding -? will do the trick:

```
^-?[1-9]+([0-9]+)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a negative number will be simply marked by a preceding `-` sign the following expression should work:

`/(^|( )|\t)(-|)\d{1,}/gm`

Explanation:

- First, `(^| )` matches a start of a new line OR (because of the `|`) a white space (from a space bar) OR a tab. If you have requirements on the white space surrounding the input, you can tweak this regular expression in this section.
- Next, `(-|)` matches either the `-` character OR (because of the `|`) nothing
- Then it matches a digit `\d`, where there is at least 1 digit, but possibly an infinite number (because of `{1,}`)
- Next, the `g` sets the global flag allowing more than one instance to be matched.
- Finally, the `m` sets the multi-line flag, allowing matches to span across lines. This is necessary for the `^` new-line character to match properly.

This was tested with the following cases:

```
-0934 sdj2a
1328 232
-93 2939 -192
```

Where the matched groups were:
`-0934`,`1328`, `232`, `-93`, `2939`, `-192`